# whay `fxLayoutAlign` behave diffrently?

Tags: html, angular, angular-flex-layout

I have 3 elements I would like to space it equally using `Angular Flex-Layout` and the following code do what I want

**first working code**

```
<mat-toolbar-row fxShow.ls-sm fxHide.gt-sm fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
   <button mat-button routerLink=""  >home</button>
   <button mat-button routerLink="/post" >   post</button>
   <button mat-button routerLink="about-us"> contact us</button>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```

has the following **output**

[image]

**second not working code**

```
<mat-toolbar-row fxShow.ls-sm fxHide.gt-sm  >
      <div fxlayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
        <button mat-button routerLink=""  >home</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/post" >   post</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="about-us"> contact us</button>
      </div>
 </mat-toolbar-row>
```

has the following **output**

[image]

### My question

I expect the two code will work the same … So **why the second code make the 3 button stacked together?**

Comment: Can you share `<mat-toolbar>` element you used please

Comment: `<mat-toolbar>` Is a part of angular material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` element you used inside `mat-toolbar-row` has no full width of parent element. So you need to add `fxFlex` as directive so it's 100% width of parent.

```
<mat-toolbar-row fxShow.ls-sm fxHide.gt-sm>
  <!-- ADD fxFlex to div -->
    <div fxFlex fxlayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <button mat-button >home</button>
        <button mat-button >   post</button>
        <button mat-button > contact us</button>
    </div>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> 1 code</p>

<mat-toolbar-row fxShow.ls-sm fxHide.gt-sm fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
   <button mat-button routerLink=""  >home</button>
   <button mat-button routerLink="/post" >   post</button>
   <button mat-button routerLink="about-us"> contact us</button>
</mat-toolbar-row>

<p> 2  code</p>

<mat-toolbar-row fxShow.ls-sm fxHide.gt-sm  >
      <div fxlayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
        <button mat-button routerLink=""  >home</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/post" >   post</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="about-us"> contact us</button>
      </div>
 </mat-toolbar-row>
```

[image: stackblitz Result]

you need to add the fxFlex directive in your second code div.